# How to use Solandra to index a Cassandra database

Tags: solr, cassandra, solandra

I am creating a Cassandra database and would like full-text indexing and searching on my Cassandra database. Several blogs and stackoverflow posts suggest indexing with Solandra, but do not say how. The Solandra wiki indicates that Solandra only provides a Cassandra back-end for Solr, not that it indexes Cassandra.

So, is Solandra able to index a Cassandra database automatically? That is to say, can I update a Cassandra database without posting data to Solandra separately?

Or, is the way to use it to both update a Cassandra database that I wish to index and simultaneously post the data to Solandra as I would with with Solr?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"can I update a Cassandra database without posting data to Solandra separately?"

Not yet.

Comment: When you say "Not yet," do you mean that this is something that is being worked or a likely upcoming feature?

Comment: Yes, once the ability to associate triggers with a column family is working, then this can be done.